# How can I test a function when I have a local variable in Angular?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I want to do something when I resize my window in that case push item1

```
export class MyComponent {
  defaultArray = [];

  @HostListener('window:resize')
  handleResize() {
    clearTimeout(this.resizeId);
    this.resizeId = setTimeout(() => {
      this. handleItemsWidth();
    }, 500);
  }
```

And after I want to test if defaultArray.length was changed

```
   handleItemsWidth() {
    const block = document ? document.getElementById('myBlock') : null;
    if (block) {
      defaultArray.push('item1');
    }
  }
}
```

There is my test case, I can't perform the action because I don't have access to local variables

```
it('should test if defaultArray length was changed', function () {
  component.defaultArray = [];
  component.handleItemsWidth();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.defaultArray.length).toBe(1);
});
```

Comment: Don't test implementation details - what's the external result of the defaultArray being longer? Also I wouldn't call the method directly, if it's possible to trigger the event instead do that.

Comment: that's a good idea for that case but how can I test something if my something depends of a local variable inside my function?

Comment: *What* "something"? There's not enough information here to tell you what a better approach might look like.

Comment: for exmaple I have a function like: 
if (window.innerHeight < 500) {
  this.state = true; // variable from component
}
but how window.innerHeight is readable only i can't set it in my tests to test if state was changed